# Typecasting in IOS from CustomObject to id

Tags: ios, casting, weak

What happens if we typecast a custom object to `id`,

i had a problem of assigning to `id` from incompatible type `Myclass* __Strong`

working code:

```
self.delegate=(id)mycustomobject;
```

then i type casted my object to `id` and it was all fine and worked as a charm.

but my question is will there be any issues that come unexpectedly later on.if so,what is the best way to avoid such warning.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the first part of your question, if you assign an object to `id` your object will loose the class association in compile time scope that means if you have a property name `myProp` of `NSString` type in your class `MyClass` and you do something like

```
id tempVar = (id)objMyClass;
```

then you won't be able to access the property `myProp` in compile time.

```
NSString *propValue =  tempVar.myProp;   // This will throw an error "Property not found".
```

To address why you were facing issue in assigning an object is because you declared the property `delegate` as an `id` type which is conforming to `MyClassProtocol` protocol, something like

```
@property (nonatomic,assign) id<MyClassProtocol> delegate;
```

However you have not conformed to `MyClassProtocol` inside your class `MyClass`. So when you are writing the code with `id` type cast, you are actually assigning an `id` type object (delegate) to an object of `MyClass` which is wrong from compiler perspective.

```
self.delegate = mycustomobject; // Wrong; delegate data type is id while your custom object is of type MyClass
```

So, when `MyClass` conform the protocol your `self` will become a data type which conforms to `MyClassProtocol` and will ultimately support `id<MyClassProtocol>` which means any data type conforming to that protocol.